# Adding text to an array from a single edittext

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an edittext and I want to add items from that edittext into an array on the click of a button, but then I find out that when I type different texts it keeps overidding the previous text so I just get one text in the array.

Please how do I get the text and add it to the array each time the button is clicked?

My code:

```
public class ReadMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout mainLayoutRead;
    EditText readEditText;
    private Button btnSaveTime;
    static ArrayList<String> saveGottenSubjects;
    TinyDB tinyDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.read_main);
        mainLayoutRead = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayoutRead);
        readEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.readEditText);
        btnSaveTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSaveTime);
        tinyDB = new TinyDB(ReadMain.this);
        saveGottenSubjects = new ArrayList<>();

        btnSaveTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String gottenSubjectread = readEditText.getText().toString();
                saveGottenSubjects.add(gottenSubjectread);
                System.out.println(saveGottenSubjects);

                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: remove the static

Comment: maybe you misunderstand something. At the end of your operation of button click, you are finishing the activity: `finish();` . That means on every click, your activity closes and everything is gone. At the next start everything will be new, so you could hold only one item.

Comment: aren´t you wondering why your app closes everytime on button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In onClick method of  btnSaveTime button. At last you call finish().
Which close the activity. So all time it Create new ArrayList. And Store At 0 index.

If you want store more values at a time than remove finish().
You can put Other button for finish. 
After getting list of Array, Before finish()you can Store it in your DB.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs : Thank you.

Comment: I can see that English is not your native tongue

Comment: Okay Thank you i will change that

Comment: @Denny: Yes. Try my level best. :)